# javascript help - Program doesn't alert

Tags: javascript, loops, alert

I'm still working on a program and I have a problem. The code is here:

```
function Calculate(){
    var elev = [];
    var inputs = document.getElementsByName("txt");
    for(i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    elev[i] = {
        "Value": inputs[i].value,
        "Used": false
    };
}

    for(j=0; j<=10; j++) {
            var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);

            if (elev[r].Used) {             //1st number
                for(var a=0; a<=21; a++) {
                    if (!elev[a].Used) {
                        elev[r].Value = elev[a].Value;
                        break;
                        }
                    else {continue; }
                    }
                }
                ...
                }
            }


            elev[r].used = true;
            doument.write(elev[r].Value);
            ...
        }
}
```

First of all, I have 22 imports to the var inputs[i].value (later elev[i]) in my HTML document. I want it to use all of the 'elev' arrays once, but I see (in my document.write as I clipped out here) it uses some of them twice and some of them isn't even used. How can I fix that?

**Problem solved by using the Fisher-Yates shuffle**

Comment: `aa` is undefined maybe?  Why are you assigning `elev[aa]` to `elev[a]`?

Comment: Try using debugging tools to step through your code to see what is going wrong here.

Comment: Hint: the JS `alert` function will skip if the passed argument is the empty string or evaluates to false otherwise. You can `alert(" > " + your_js_var);` to avoid this.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp - alerting empty strings and false work as expected for me in Chrome.  Which browser is doing that for you?

Comment: I uses elev[aa] for checking if elev[a]/elev[r] is used.

Comment: I have seen this behaviour many times in the past. FF I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me point out several problems with your script

First of all this section

```
for(i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
   elev[i] = inputs[i].value;
   elev[i].used = false;
}
```

You are assigning the value to the array but it is of type `String`. String does not get the properties.

The following code will work

```
var obj = {};
obj.SomeProp = true;
```

But if you do so

```
var str = "";
str.SomeProp = true;
```

attempt to use `str.SomeProp` will always return `undefined`
The code `if (elev[r].used)` will always be evaluated to false (because `0`, empty string, `false`, `null` and `undefined` behaves as false in `if` operator in JavaScript)
So I suggest you to refactor your code into

```
for(i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    elev[i] = {
        "Value": inputs[i].value,
        "Used": false
    }; // Pay attention, I added an object and Used property starts with an uppercase letter.
    // Then further in the code you'll use elev[index].Value in order to use the value
}
```

And finally the block `if (elev[aa].used = false)` will not throw exception, but this is a error.

Consider the following snipped

```
var someVal = true;
if (someVal = false)
    alert("That's wierd");
alert(someVal);
```

It will work because you are assigning the value false to the `someVal` variable and this instruction is evaluated to true. Some the alert with message `That's wierd` will appear. Furthermore, you'll notice that the `someVal`'s value is `false`.
This snipped uses the equality operator which will be evaluated to false and the first alert will not work out. However there is a problem too. A stylistic one. Never check the value for false, especially in JavaScript.

```
var someVal = true;
if (someVal == false)
    alert("That's wierd");
alert(someVal);
```

The correct snippet must look like this.

```
var someVal = true;
if (someVal)
    alert("There you go!");
alert(someVal);
```

P.S.

You get the variable `aa` from nowhere. Where does it come from? It must be undefined. What did you want?
Concatinated values of two numbers? The sum of them?

**EDIT:**

Just a few notices.

1) Use `for (var a = 0; a < someConstant; a++)` syntax. Don't forget to add var keyword.

2) Use proper indention, i.e.

```
if (someCondition){
    // Some instruction
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //more indention
    }
}
```

3) Don't use `empty` else block.

Comment: Thank you for the very good answer. I just have a questions. First, when I'm gonna call my elev array (object), I need to write like 'elev[5].Value' ? It's not a problem, just a question. **EDIT:** With the varible aa i just wanted to check if the elev[r] was used.

Comment: Yes you have to. You are storing an object instead of just a single value. It has two properties and one of them hold the actual value and the second is a boolean value to indicate some state. (Used or not in this case)

Comment: If you want to check whether it is used use `if (!elev[a].Used) {/* Do something with elev[a].Value*/}`

Comment: Great. After I have eaten my dinner, I will try to update the whole script with the new knowledge. I it all works well, you'll of course get the answer mark. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ohm... Can you please take a look at the edit at the first post, it's been updated, but it still doesn't work. This is the final thing.